# Having some ModelForms at the same page with some similar Field Name

Tags: python, django

I've put forms of these model(via ModelForm) at the same page but similar Field Names have made some problem for me:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
   ServiceProvider=models.ForeignKey(ServiceProvider)
   Vehicle=models.ForeignKey(Vehicle)
   From=models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name='FromLocation')
   To=models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name='ToLocation')
   PriceUnit=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   Class=models.ForeignKey(Class)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
   Date=models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Visit(models.Model):
   Location=models.ForeignKey(Location)
   FromDate=models.CharField(max_length=16)
   ToDate=models.CharField(max_length=16)

class Accommodate(models.Model):
   Location=models.ForeignKey(Location)
   PriceUnit=models.ForeignKey(PriceUnit)
   FromDate=models.CharField(max_length=16)
   ToDate=models.CharField(max_length=16)
   Price=models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

I googled and just found about formset,How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the forms a [prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms) e.g.

```
transfer = TransferForm(prefix="transfer")
visit = VisitForm(prefix="visit")
accommodate = AccommodateForm(prefix="accommodate")
```